# Client-side file conversion

Tags: web-applications, client-side

I want to convert various file formats to pdf in a web application. One way to do this; upload the file to server and convert it with [jodconverter](http://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/). But since it consumes CPU and memory, i am looking for a client-side solution.

For example; if there were a java-applet to do this, it would be great. Any other suggestions?